# Can't understand this module/type error

Tags: json, haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to use the Aeson JSON library in haskell. Right now, i just need to use "decode" to read a JSON dump.

```
import Data.Aeson
import Data.ByteString as BS
import Control.Applicative

main :: IO ()
main = print $ decode <$> BS.readFile "json"
```

I got the following error when trying to compile/run it:

```
Couldn't match type 'ByteString'
with 'Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString'
NB: 'ByteString is defined in 'Data.ByteString.Internal'
    'Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString'
     is defined in 'Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
```

This error doesn't make sense to me. I tried importing the files described by ghc, but the import either fails or doesn't solve the problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two variants of `ByteString`: A strict (the default one), exported by `Data.ByteString`, and a lazy one, exported by `Data.ByteString.Lazy`.

Aeson works on top of lazy byte string, so you should change your second line to

```
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS
```